# Add Info Bubbles to Here Maps

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api, infobubble

how to add Info Bubbles to HERE maps. I follow the steps on the HERE api page, but the info bubble doesn't popup.

According to the Here api, here is the way to add popup.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/map-controls.html

```
var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({ lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }, {
        content: '<b>Hello World!</b>'
       });

// Add info bubble to the UI:
ui.addBubble(bubble);
```

I follow the code and the map loads correctly with the right coordinates, but I don't see any info bubble on the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, 
      width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  //Initialize the Platform object:
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': '{YOUR_APP_ID} ',
    'app_code': '{YOUR_APP_CODE} '
      useHTTPS: true
    });
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
      tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
      ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
    });

    //Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      defaultLayers.normal.map, {pixelRatio: pixelRatio});

    //Step 3: make the map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

  // Get the default map types from the Platform object:

        map.setCenter({lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51});
    map.setZoom(10);
  // Instantiate the map:


  // Create the default UI:
  var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, 'de-DE');
  var mapSettings = ui.getControl('mapsettings');
var zoom = ui.getControl('zoom');
var scalebar = ui.getControl('scalebar');
var panorama = ui.getControl('panorama');

panorama.setAlignment('top-left');
mapSettings.setAlignment('top-left');
zoom.setAlignment('top-left');
scalebar.setAlignment('top-left');
var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({ lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }, {
        content: '<b>Hello World!</b>'
       });

// Add info bubble to the UI:
ui.addBubble(bubble);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Richard and I'm a developer evangelist for HERE.

Your code breaks in this line:

```
panorama.setAlignment('top-left');
```

This line indicates that you want to move the StreetLevel UI element to the top-left of the map. However this element does not exist, as you've forgotten to import the *mapsjs-pano.js* library. This library is required for StreetLevel functionality. Add the following line to your  and your code should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-pano.js"></script>
```

Also note that you are missing a comma after setting your app_code and that your importing some libraries twice. You may have to fix these issues as well for your code to work. Here is a cleaned up version of your code that does what you want to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-pano.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />
        <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >

            function createInfoBubble(map) {
                // Create info bubble
                var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({ lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }, {
                    content: '<b>Hello World!</b>'
                });
                // Add info bubble to the UI:
                ui.addBubble(bubble);
            }

            // Step 1: initialize the platform
            var platform = new H.service.Platform({
                app_id: '{YOUR_APP_ID}',
                app_code: '{YOUR_APP_CODE}',
                useHTTPS: true
            });

            var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
            var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
                tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
                ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
            });

            // Step 2: initialize a map
            var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                defaultLayers.normal.map, {pixelRatio: pixelRatio});

            // Step 3: make the map interactive            
            var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

            // Step 4: create the default UI components
            var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

            // Move UI elements to the top left of the map
            var mapSettings = ui.getControl('mapsettings');
            var zoom = ui.getControl('zoom');
            var scalebar = ui.getControl('scalebar');
            var panorama = ui.getControl('panorama');

            panorama.setAlignment('top-right');
            mapSettings.setAlignment('top-left');
            zoom.setAlignment('top-left');
            scalebar.setAlignment('top-left');

            // Move map to Berlin
            map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
            map.setZoom(14);

            createInfoBubble(map);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I'm a developer evangelist for HERE." If that's the case then could you tell the dev team that infobubbles should not cover the markers? If you set both the marker and bubble to the same position (the bubble giving info about the marker) then the bubble is before  the marker. There should be a z-order setting, so the bubble is behind the marker. You can see the problem in your official example, if you click on a marker to show its infobubble: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/open-infobubble   The bubble hides the marker and if you zoom in it keeps hiding it.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the feedback and I will forward it to the team. I can say that we are actively working to improve the InfoBubble in one of our upcoming releases.

Comment: thanks, that works. Is there a way to make the default blue marker bigger?

Comment: I don't think you can change the size of the default icon, but you can simply use your own image (SVG or Bitmap), like so:

var icon = new H.map.Icon('biggerIcon.png');
var marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }, { icon: icon });
map.addObject(marker);

Comment: Hi Tom, Is there a way to add InfoBubbles in Android?